# How to send additional parameters to an SDL Thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parameters, sdl

Yes, I know how to create an SDL thread.

```
int myfunc(void* data)
{
    //my code...
}
SDL_CreateThread* mythread=SDL_CreateThread(myfunc,NULL);
```

But what if i want to do something like:

```
int myfunc(void* data,int myparameter1,char myparameter2)
{
    //my code...
}
SDL_CreateThread* mythread=SDL_CreateThread(myfunc,NULL,42,'c');
```

i.e how to create a thread for a function with more than one parameters (parameters excluding the usual 'void* data')
If this is not possible can you suggest any method by which i can pass a parameter to a thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a `struct` on the heap, set its fields with your data, then pass its address to `SDL_CreateThread`:

```
typedef struct {
    int param1;
    char param2;
} ThreadData;

int myfunc(void* data)
{
    ThreadData *tdata = data;
    int param1 = tdata->param1;
    char param2 = tdata->param2;
    free(data); // depending on the content of `data`, this may have
                // to be something more than a single `free`
    //my code...
}
ThreadData *data = malloc(sizeof(ThreadData));
data->param1 = ...;
data->param2 = ...;
SDL_CreateThread* mythread=SDL_CreateThread(myfunc,data);
```

Comment: It seems to me that either doing an `malloc`/`free` is redundant, or copying the data into the local stack of the thread. Right?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure whether SDL threads need to be joined or not (or whether this is the norm there) but if it is, you need nether the heap allocation nor the copying of parameters onto local stack. This is because of the fact that if you join with the child thread in the main thread, then the lifetime of the arguments in the main thread's stack will be guaranteed to encompass the lifetime of the child thread.

Comment: @yzt:  The heap allocation was to ensure that the data didn't get overwritten in case the encompassing function that called `SDL_CreateThread` `return`ed before the thread had looked at it.  The copying of the variables onto the local stack was nothing more than to show how to use the `struct` members;  it can/should be changed to something more sensible.

Comment: Please note that on my eclipse IDE, the statement `ThreadData *tdata = data;` had an error and i had to replace it with `ThreadData *tdata = (ThreadData*)data;`